# DDD and edit of Aggregate's descendants

Tags: domain-driven-design, domain-model

In a DDD approach, suppose I have an `Order` (this is my aggregate root) and a `Line` (a descendant of an `Order`). In both objects I have private setter for properties and a builder that handle creations of the cluster of object.

As far as I know every action on the cluster goes through the aggregate root. Is this right?
For instance, if I need a command to hide a *line* I can't have simply an `hide()` method on the `Line` object, but instead I should have an `hideLine()` method in the aggregate root that traverse the cluster of object down to the `Line`.

At this point I imagine a scenario like that:

```
// in the aggregate root
public void HideLine(Line line){
    line.Hide();
}

// in the Line class
public void Hide(){
   this.Hidden = true;
}
```

but in this way someone could do something like:

```
Order orderA = _repo.getById(id_A);
Order orderB = _repo.GetById(id_B);

orderB.HideLine(orderA.Lines.First());
```

with unknown side effects (right now the side effect is clear, but in a more complex scenario this could create headache).

So I could take this counter-measures:

- Accept an id as parameter for `HideLine` mehtd (i.e. public void `HideLine(Guid lineId)`)
- Check in `HideLine(Line line)` method that `line` is actually in `Order.Lines` collection

How I handle consistency issues? Are my solutions meaningful or I have completly miss the point?

### Post scriptum after comment(s)

@Songo: The `Order` aggregate (note: in my real scenario it isn't an Order but a more complex cluster) starts a saga/process manager during its life that oversees the `Order` publishing process (try to imagine that in a real scenario an order need to be published). As soon `OrderPublishingRequestEvent` is catched the saga starts and try to validate the `Order` checking if each `Line` is valid, and if not the line will be hided.
Thus my command handler is something like:

```
public void Handle(OrderValidationCommand message)
{
    // get the aggregate
    Order order = _repository.GetById(message.OrderId);

    // call a service to make validation
    foreach (Line line in order.Lines)
    {
        var result = validator.Validate(line);

        if (result.IsValid)
            order.HideLine(line);
        else
            // do something else
    }

    order.Validate(); // raise event ValidatedOrderEvent
    _repository.Update(fornitura);
}
```

Comment: Just wondering, but where did the `Line` object in `public void HideLine(Line line)` come from? I mean surely it didn't come from the database because only aggregates have repositories.

Comment: I answered. Check the updated question and let me know what do you think about it.

Comment: hmmmm why don't you make a function `order.validateLines(validator)` to encapsulate the validation logic?

Comment: And what about to call the validator directly inside the aggregate?
Doing `order.validateLines()` without parameter? Does this create a problem of high coupling avoidable in aggregate?

Comment: well it depends :) Validation is a nasty topic which depends  on the context. Why are you validating the order? Normally I would validate the aggregate in the constructor or in a dedicated factory class if the validation logic is complex enough. A validator is a service which may change implementation at some time and I hate injecting service s inside entities. It all depends on the complexity of the validation.

Comment: The validation's requirements are pretty stable and shared. That's why we have create a new project and shared it through a custom NuGet repository.

Comment: just wondering, why you do validation for order inside order entity, but validation for line by external validator? Is it inconsistent? Either way, is it better to have only one validation that validates both order and line at the same time? I don't say an order is valid if one of its line is invalid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Command Handler doesn't seem like the best place to put line hiding logic. It should contain orchestration but not domain rules.

Is there a way you could give the validator to `Order` and have it validate itself, as a single action executed in one transaction ? That would solve the `Line` access problem at the same time.

Maybe this would be more in line with the domain too, since I doubt you have "hide a line" as part of your ubiquitous language. It seems to me more like a side effect of validating Order lines, not a domain requirement.

Comment: You're right. This sounds good. The question is (I imagine the answer but just t be sure....): why order can't call the validator and do the validation in a way completly autonomus?

Comment: Yes, why not ? Whether the `Order` receives the `Validator` from outside or instantiates it directly probably depends on whether the `Validator` needs references to data from outside the aggregate. Validator could also be a simple Specification if the validation logic doesn't require external resources.